# How can I write a function in python to write the file names of directory with the output of my function to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, glob, traversal

im very new to python and trying to understand how to work with traversing.

#my code that works-

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
df = pd.read_csv("1003285474_1003285465_0a54173ed4c58b7354e0dd48.csv",encoding="utf-8")
s = ' '.join(df['transcript'])

sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
sid.polarity_scores(s)
Out[68]: {'neg': 0.046, 'neu': 0.707, 'pos': 0.247, 'compound': 0.9922}
```

As you see above I have 2 functions, one that joins all rows of a column and another that returns the sentiment polarity scores. my objective is to traverse through a folder and do the above for all csvs in that folder.
My final objective is to have a dataframe that has the below-

```
filename                                             neg    neu    pos     compound
1003285474_1003285465_0a54173ed4c58b7354e0dd48.csv   0.046  0.707  0.247   0.9922
1003285474_1003285465_0a54173ed4c58b7354e0dd41.csv   0.192  0.731  0.122   0.7222
```

How should i traverse through all the csv files apply the above to functions and get the above results to a dataframe for all those csvs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os    
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

# use glob to get a list of csv files in a folder
files = glob('path/to/folder/*.csv')
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
# use dict comprehension to apply you analysis
data = {os.path.basename(file): sid.polarity_scores(' '.join(pd.read_csv(file, encoding="utf-8")['transcript'])) for file in files}
# create a data frame from the dictionary above
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create a function to wrap your analysis:

```py
def analyse_data(file_path):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, encoding='utf-8')
    s = ' '.join(df['transcript'])

    sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
    score = sid.polarity_scores(s)
    score['filename'] = os.path.basename(file_path)
```

This function takes a path to a file and returns a row in your final data frame. An example return would be:

```py
{'filename': '1003285474_1003285465_0a54173ed4c58b7354e0dd48.csv', 'neg': 0.046, 'neu': 0.707, 'pos': 0.247, 'compound': 0.9922}
```

Then, use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to loop through all files in a directory and apply that function.

```py
def create_dataframe(root_dir):
    data = []
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
        for file_name in files:
            full_path = os.path.join(path, file_name)
            data.append(analyse_data(full_path))

    return pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I suppose that only CSVs files exist under `root_dir` and its sub-directories, therefore it is not necessary to check for file type before applying the analysis function.